# ViewPagerIndicator returns error when executed on IntelliJIDEA

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

I have used Jake Wharton ViewPagerIndicator, It was running   well before  but after some time it starts showing this error when I try to run the app.

```
...
<com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/vIndicator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/view_pager_indicator_text_color"
        app:footerIndicatorHeight="3dp"
        app:footerIndicatorStyle="underline"
        app:footerLineHeight="1dp"
        app:selectedBold="true"
        app:selectedColor="@color/white" />
...
```

This is the error it shows when I try to run the app

```
android-apt-compiler: [MalariaAndroidApp]     C:\Users\Chimdi\IdeaProjects\HelloAndroid\MalariaAndroidApp\res\layout\activity_main.xml:15: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'footerIndicatorHeight' in package 'com.peacecorps.malaria'

android-apt-compiler: [MalariaAndroidApp] C:\Users\Chimdi\IdeaProjects\HelloAndroid\MalariaAndroidApp\res\layout\activity_main.xml:15: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'footerIndicatorStyle' in package 'com.peacecorps.malaria'
```

Please what can be the cause of the error?

Answer (score 0):

same here when i used compile 'com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1'

my solution was to change the grandle´s to this..

[root]\build.grandle

```
buildscript{...}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven" }
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

[root]\app\build.grandle

```
app{..}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.+'
    compile 'com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1@aar'
}
```